# Como definir focus no jhtmlarea?

Tags: jquery

Estou obtendo erro ao usar o plugin [JHtmlArea](https://github.com/crpietschmann/jHtmlArea):

> An invalid form control with name='descricao' is not focusable.

HTML

```html
<div style="float: left; width:60%; padding:0; margin:0 auto;">  
    <h1 style="text-align:center; width:100%"">Descrição do assunto</h1><br />
    <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea><br /> <br />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#descricao").htmlarea();

  $("#contato").on("submit", function (){
      if($("iframe").val().trim() == "")   {
          alert("Preencha a descrição do e-mail");
          $("#descricao").prop("required",true);
      } else {    
          $("#descricao").prop("required",false);
      }  
  });
```

Onde estou errando?

A `jhtmlarea` esta funcionando, mas não consigo barrar o envio com o campo descrição vazio nem colocar o foco nela para preenchimento.

Onde estou errando?
Vale lembra que o plugin cria um `iframe` e torna a `textarea` `display: none`.

Comment: adicionar required ao plugin. esse é o problema. Já coloquei o link d plugin.

Comment: Não, é falta de atenção mesmo. Mas corrigi aqui. Mas ainda não consigo colocar o focus() no jhtmlarea.

Comment: Voce está tendo problema para fazer a validação ou somente para jogar o focu no campo

Comment: Os dois. Na verdade, quando o plugin entra em cena, ele esconde o textarea e mostra um iframe por cima. Só que, se não tiver nada preenchido eu não consigo enviar um alerta e nesse caso não mostra erro nem nada para o usuario, apenas não submete o form

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Achei que tinha conseguido conforme resposta que dei abaixo. Mas nã deu certo não!

Answer (score 0):

Se um input estiver como "required", o form será inválido e não conseguirá enviar. O caso do foco, se o input estiver oculto, não conseguirá colocar foco.

Comment: O colega, desculpa. Enquanto você respondia estava editando a pergunta, Dá uma olhada de novo fazendo favor!

Comment: Agora que vi.
Se um input estiver como "required", o form será inválido e não conseguirá enviar. 
O caso do foco, se o input estiver oculto, não conseguirá colocar foco.

Comment: O campo não esta oculto e nem tem required no campo pois não sei em quem colocar o required, se no textarea ou no jhtmlarea. Mas em nenhum funcionou.

Comment: o required deve ser colocado no textarea.

Comment: sim. Isso é um plugin que fornece ferramentas do word para edição do texto. Tipo, negrito, itálico, sublinhado. Essas coisas.

Comment: veja esse link referente ao foco: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615861/set-focus-to-jhtmlarea-jquery-plugin

Comment: Já tinha visto esse link não é isso não. Preciso é colocar o focou em um iframe que o plugin cria para sobrepor a textarea e coloca display none nela. dá pra ver em: http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/ no formulário de contato que tem no final da página

Comment: Ainda não consegui!

Answer (score 0):

Isso funcionou para mim.

Criei um .js com esse código e importei onde tivesse jhtmlarea

```
  $("#contato").on("submit", function (){
    if($('#descricao').val() == "")   {     //verifica apena o texto
        alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
        $('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
          if ($(this).children('iframe').length){
             var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
             iframe.contentWindow.focus();
          }
       });
       return false;
    } 
  });
```

Porém ainda não consigo ao invés de validar o iframe com JScript, validar com html5 tratando a propriedade require com true e evitar a famosa janelinha popup do JScript.

Comment: doce ilusão: funcionou! Mas parou o restante do JQuery. Alguma saída?

Answer (score 0):

O campo que quer validar é

```
<textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea>
```

Por isso deverá validar a textarea e não o iframe que a biblioteca cria.

```
$("#contato").on("submit", function (){
  if($("#descricao").val() == "")   {
      alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
  } else {    
      alert("Obrigado pela descrição");
  }  
});
```

Não funciona porque a maioria dos casos porque basta ter um entar e ficará com o seguinte valor

```
<p></p><h3></h3><p></p><div><br></div><div><br></div>
```

Portanto não é vazio logo é valido.
Para voce conseguir dar focus é o seguinte codigo.:

```
$('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
    if ($(this).children('iframe').length){
        var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    }
});
```

O que sugiro é.:

```
$("#contato").on("submit", function (){
  var a=document.createElement('div'); //cria uma div temporaria
  $(a).html($('#descricao').val());    //insere o html na div
  if($(a).text().trim() == "")   {     //verifica apena o texto
      alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
      $("#descricao")
         .val('')
         .prop("required",true)
      ;
      $('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
        if ($(this).children('iframe').length){
           var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
           iframe.contentWindow.focus();
        }
     });
  } else {    
      alert("Obrigado pela descrição");
  }  
});
```

Comment: Entendi. Mas ai surgem dois problemas 1) Os outros campos do formulário estão sendo validados com htm5 validate e não com JavaScript. Logo, estou colocando $("#descricao").prop("required",true); mas como o plugin faz display: none com a textarea, logo não é possivel colocar o foco na textarea.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Já está tudo ok?

Comment: Olha, reduzi sua solução e obtive o mesmo resultado. Porém ainda não consigo ao invés de validar o iframe com JScript, validar com html5 tratando a propriedade require com true e evitar a famosa janelinha popup do JScript. Veja a solução que reduzi na minha resposta à pergunta logo abaixo! Vê se tem como me ajudar mais!

Comment: Voce apagou codigo importante. Com o codigo completo. Não funcionou?

Comment: dá esse erro: An invalid form control with name='descricao' is not focusable. O plugin jHtmlArea faz display: none ao textarea e nesse caso, não adianta fazer required pois dará erro. Não conheço outra maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma prática e funcional é criar uma função para verificar se o campo `<textarea>` com o plugin **jHtmlArea** está vazio e focar nele:

```
function checa(){
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    $(a).html($('#descricao').val());
    if($(a).text().trim() == ""){
        alert("Vazio");
        $('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
            if($(this).children('iframe').length){
                var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
                iframe.contentWindow.focus();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

E coloca no seu `<form>` o `onsubmit="return checa()"`.