# estado cidade JQuery erro na seleção

Tags: jquery, html

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).delegate('#estado', 'change', function() {
    var valor = $('#estado').val();
    $('#cidade').load('_requires/cidades.php?estado=' + valor );
   });

  $(document).delegate('#cidade', 'change', function() {
    var valor = $('#cidade').val();
    alert(valor);
    $('#bairro').load('_requires/bairros.php?cidade=' + valor );
   });

 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <label class="labelPequena">Estado</label><br />
   <select class="typeTextMedio" id="estado" name="estado" required>
      <option value="">Escolha o Estado</option>
      <option value="MG">MG</option>
      <option value="ES">ES</option>
      <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
      <option value="SP">SP</option>         
   </select>
</div>

<div>
   <label class="labelPequena">Cidade</label><br />
   <select class="typeTextMedio" id="cidade" name="cidade" required>
      <option value="">Escolha a Cidade</option>         
   </select>
</div>

<div>
   <label class="labelPequena">Bairro</label><br />
   <select class="typeTextMedio" id="bairro" name="bairro" required>
     <option value="#">Indiferente</option>

   </select>
</div>
```

Quando selecionar na `combo estados`, popular a `combo cidades`. Isto esta funcionando.

Quando selecionar na `combo cidades`, popular a `combo bairro`. Isto NÃO esta funcionando. Mas observei que na `combo cidades` só ocorre o **ERRO** com a primeira cidade apenas e quando clico nela, o evento não ocorre. Com as demais normalmente ocorre.

Uma observação importante é que se escolher segunda cidade da `combo`, e a `combo` dos bairros é carregada, então voltar e selecionar a primeira cidade novamente, então agora funciona. Na primeira tentativa nem o `alert` funciona!

Como resolver?

Comment: A parte em PHP está recebendo e retornando os dados corretamente?

Comment: Sim. Tudo normal, as combos se enchem normalmente. O problema é que ao selecionar um estado a primeira opção de cidade não dispara o evento para popular a combo bairros. Mas da segunda cidade em diante funciona. E, depois da seguida cidade, se voltar na primeira, então agora ela funciona.

Comment: tenta fazer o BIND do CHANGE da CIDADE  só após   a volta da chamada ao escolher ESTADO  $('#cidade').load('_requires/cidades.php?estado=' + valor );

Comment: http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/buscaAvancada.php

Comment: o combo de cidade é inicialmente carregado com <option value="">Escolha a Cidade</option>. - verifique se quando você trás as cidades do estado selecionado, esse option esta sendo retornado junto com os resultados. Se não tiver, faça isso então.

Comment: eu inspecionei o elemento e notei que o option="" sumiu das opções do select. Só fica as opções das cidades mesmo

Answer (score 2):

O problema está ocorrendo porque voce não esta retornando junto com os resultados das cidades o option Escolha a Cidade. Desta forma a primeira cidade vem por default como selecionada mas sem ativar o change do combo.

Outra forma de resolver o problema é trocar o código javascript combo #Estado para:

```
$(document).delegate('#estado', 'change', function() {
    var valor = $('#estado').val();
    $('#cidade').load('_requires/cidades.php?estado=' + valor, function() {
       $('#cidade').trigger('change');
   });

 });
```

Observe que o trigger vai invocar o evento de change no combo de #cidade.

Comment: Acho que isso resolve.

Comment: quando faço $('#cidade').trigger('change');, a combo bairros é automaticamente populada mas parece que envia valor vazio para o php como parâmetro da cidade e então retorna sem bairros. Mas mesmo assim, ao selecionar manualmente a cidade então a consulta é feita normamente

Comment: o trigger não funcionou então, pq antes dos valores da cidade retornar, ele invocou a função que popula o bairro. Para funcionar teria que colocar o trigger dentro de um timeOut ou então dentro de um Callback. Mas selecionando manualmente vai resolver. Verifiquei que quando troca o estado o combo de bairro continua populado. Adiciona um codigo para limpar o combo de bairro tambem

Comment: É, testando aqui, mesmo assim não deixa selecionar a primeira opção do mesmo jeito. Vê ai: http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/buscaAvancada.php

Comment: Como seria colocar o trigger dentro de um timeOut ou então dentro de um Callback?

Comment: Voce não adicionou o option Selecione sua Cidade. Adiciona isso ai pra eu testar.

Comment: Se você chamar a URL nao traz serviços @Carlos Rocha  http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/_requires/cidades.php?estado=SP

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta, colocando o trigger dentro do callback. Tenta dessa forma.

Comment: Ainda esta sendo desenvolvido, só tem cidades cadastradas em MG http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/_requires/cidades.php?estado=MG

Comment: faz os acertos que te falei e libera la naquele link para a gente testar.

Comment: ja foi. Atualizado

Comment: Aqui, não querendo incomodar, mas já incomodando. Estou com uma uma outra dúvida meio que parada e por mais que eu pesquise e tente não consigo solucionar. Será que tem como me ajudar fazendo favor? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124948/como-definir-focus-no-jhtmlarea