# Marcação em checkboxes select multiselect parou

Tags: jquery

estou usando o plugin multiselect JQuery de : http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Bom, estou usando a função abaixo que verifica as opções marcadas

```
for (i = 0; i < $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes").length; i++) {  
  $ui = $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes");
  $indiferente = $ui.find("[title=Indiferente]");
  $indiferente.prop("checked", true);
  $ui.find("input").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("title") != "Indiferente" && this.checked){
        $indiferente.prop("checked", false); //desmarco indiferente se algum
                                            //outro for selecionado
    }
    if(!$ui.find("input:checked").length){ //se nenhum input estiver marcado
        $indiferente.prop("checked",true); //marco indiferente

    }
  })

  $indiferente.change(function(){                 //quando indiferente mudar
    if(this.checked){                             //se estiver marcado
        $ui.find("input").not("[title=Indiferente]").prop("checked", false);                       
                                                  //desmarco outros
    }           
  })

  $("#ui-multiselect-tipo-option-0").click(); 
  $("#ui-multiselect-bairro-option-0").click();

 }
```

Obviamente atrelei o plugin aos campos select

```
$("#tipo").multiselect();
$("#bairro").multiselect();
```

Mas a parte das marcações parou de funcionar

```
});
```

Onde errei?

Comment: Ola, Na console qual é o erro que dá? Consegue replicar o constragimento por exemplo no jsfiddle para uma melhor analise?

Comment: Oi, observei que se eu fechar }): antes de $("#tipo").multiselect(); o problema para. Mas não consigo entender.

Comment: Sem erros no console.

Comment: ok, coloque $("#tipo").multiselect();
$("#bairro").multiselect(); antes do for. Deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo! Pode me ajudar nesta outra dúvida fazendo favor? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124948/como-definir-focus-no-jhtmlarea/125656#125656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O constrangimento estava a surgir porque quando passava no for não existiam os objetos.

Por isso altere.:

```
$("#tipo").multiselect();
$("#bairro").multiselect();
```

Para o inicio da função.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: hum, entendi. Pode me ajudar nessa também fazendo favor? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124948/como-definir-focus-no-jhtmlarea/125656#125656